# Pass reference of static method to a function

Tags: swift, function, parameter-passing, static-methods

I found in `Swift` you can store a reference of a static method without actually executing it:

```
class StringMama {
    static func returnString(s:String)->String {
      return s
    }
}

var stored = StringMama.returnString
print(stored.self) // (Function)
print(stored(s:"Hello!")) // for some reason it doesn't work
print(stored("Hello!")) // it works
```

Now, I want to pass `stored` as an argument of a function to execute the function later, in the body of the function. Is this possible? How? I could not found a way. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Unrelated, but using postfix `.self` on an expression just returns that expression; so you can just say `print(stored)` instead of `print(stored.self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    printUsingReference(stored, "the")


static func printUsingReference(_ stored: (_ s: String) -> String, _ content: String) {
    print(stored(content))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so like this:

```
func Foo(param: (String) -> String) {
    print(param("Foo called"))
}

// Pass it your stored var
Foo(param: stored)
```

Comment: Curiously, I've tried the same and it didn't work, afterwards I tried your code and it worked (maybe some caching issue with playground)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use the closure? store its reference to variable and get value from that and pass in your function.

```
var someValue: (String) -> String = { stringValue in
  return stringValue
}

func someFunction(value: String) {
 print(value)
}

//Now pass closure reference into one variable 
let value = someValue
//Using in that function like below.
someFunction(value: value("test"))
```